# Sometimes tabs in notepad++ won't make a new window when dragged out

Tags: notepad++, tabs

Long-time Linux user on a Windows 7 machine, using Notepad++ to edit multiple text files.

Sometimes I can drag a tab out of the notepad++ window  onto the desktop to get a new notepad++ window.  This is a very nice feature.  But sometimes when I try to drag a tab out, nothing happens.  I don't see what is different about these tabs or the files they contain.  It is repeatable; the same tab still won't make a new window.

I'm not familiar enough with Windows and its strange ways to begin to guess what is going on, unless it's a bug.   How can I make all tabs draggable-to-new-windowable, no exceptions?

Comment: If you right click the tab and select Move to New Instance do you see the same behavior?

Comment: @darenw Are you still facing the problem. I am able drag and drop and create tabs new notepad++ windows without any problem. I am using NPP(6.1).I might not have understood your question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notepad++ doesn't allow the "drag tab to create a new window" feature unless the file that has been modified is **saved** (or if the file is new). If this problem persists even after the file is saved, try right-clicking the tab and choosing 'Move to New Instance'.

Comment: +1 for "unless the file that has been modified is saved (or if the file is new)". Until today I had always thought that this was a massive bug with Notepad++, and was at a loss to understand why it hadn't been fixed by the developers, never occured to me that whether or not it worked was based on whether the file was saved!

Comment: Just as a clarification, this is likely not a bug but just a limitation of how it was implemented. Tabs are not isolated into individual processes, and Notepad++ does not support floating windows. So it cannot move data that does not exist into a new instance. The procedure it's doing is basically closing the file, opening a new instance of Notepad++, and having it reopen the file again. It will block the behavior if the data is not saved on disk because it cannot recover unsaved data.